# reset form doesnt work after history.go

Tags: javascript, php

i have searched here and there but nothing seems to work.
after submitting my form, i want it to automatically go back to the form, all clear fields.
but my code doesnt work. it only go back one page,with all the values i entered.

in my saveForm.php

```
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
            {
                ?><script>
                    alert('Saved Successfully!');
                    window.history.go(-1);
                    resetForms();
                </script><?php
            }
```

in my script

```
function resetForms(){
    var i;
    for (i = 0; (i < document.forms.length); i++) {
        document.forms[i].reset();$('#form-addmaker').clearForm();
    }
}
```

am i missing something.or maybe just messing it all worse.

Comment: When you go to a new page with `window.history.go()`, the script on the current page stops running.

Comment: Why don't you just return a redirect to the URL with the empty form?

Comment: Also, when going back using *history.go*, a load event isn't dispatched when the page is reloaded.

Comment: thanks for the fact.
is there other solution for this?

Comment: Try this - execute  resetForms  function on load - put it in document.ready function. It might work.